# Relationship between Ethereum block and Whisper

Tags: go-ethereum, whisper

When a message is sent to another node with a whisper, it is immediately visible regardless of the block. If so, does the block have a record of using whisper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whisper is done entirely off-chain. Nothing about the Whisper protocol is stored in blocks.

Comment: Then the whisper is not saved? In any format ?? Can not you see who's whispering?

Comment: No, Whispers are not permanently saved. Whisper is a protocol for ephemeral p2p  communication. If you want a log of messages, you'll have to store them on the sender/receiver.